# Python Requests - Cannot import HTTPProxyAuth (AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'HTTPPRoxyAuth')

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

At the top of my Python file, I have:

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPPRoxyAuth
```

The line `auth = requests.auth.HTTPPRoxyAuth(username, password)` spits out the error `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'HTTPPRoxyAuth'`, which leads back to a `ImportError: cannot import name HTTPPRoxyAuth` at the import line.

I can look at `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\requests\auth.py` and see the `HTTPProxyAuth` class.

I can use `from requests.auth import *` and look at all the modules with

```
g = globals().copy()
for name, obj in g.iteritems():
        print name
```

and see `HTTPProxyAuth` in the list, but I'm still receiving an `AttributeError`.

Can someone explain why it's not importing correctly? I'm using Python 2.7 and Requests 2.18.4

Answer (score 0):

The R in Proxy has to be lower case:

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPProxyAuth
```